# SQL #1064 error but i can't figure it out

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NULL , `cashExp` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'غير معروف' , `cashDa...' at line 1

[this is an image of what i did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIE8M.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `balancemapper`.`homedata` (
    `cash` DOUBLE(100000) NULL , 
    `cashExp` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'غير معروف' , 
    `cashDate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
    `cashComms` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'لا يوجد' , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`cash`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

i can't figure it out i searched online but can't

i tried changing the default value from null to anything else and to none and null but no difference

i tried changing the date to varchar but nothing changed

i changed teh length also nothing changed

Comment: I dont think having `cash` as a primary key makes any sense either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` takes either two arguments or none. You can't give it a single argument.

MariaDB does not support a precision of 100000 digits. I recall the limit is 255.

```
CREATE TABLE `balancemapper`.`homedata` (
    `cash` DOUBLE(100000,2) NULL
);

Error: Display width out of range for 'cash' (max = 255)
```

Also if you are storing currency values in the `cash` column, you shouldn't use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` anyway. You should use `DECIMAL` for a fixed-precision scaled data type.

See also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/double/

Comment: thanks for the answer this helped me i used decimal
but can decimal be used in caculations i'm pretty new

Comment: Yes, decimal is a numeric data type and you can use it in calculations. It is preferred to use decimal when working with currency values.

Comment: I just want to tell you that my project is nearly done and there are 0 problems with the database thank you for making me understand databases more